# Salesforce Lightning App + Microsoft Edge + CSP

Tags: lightning, content-security-policy, microsoft-edge

I am currently developing a Lightning Application and have predominately being using Google Chrome through the development process. I am now working to ensure that the application is supported across multiple browsers, including Microsoft Edge (Currently supported with LEX).

Everything is working great in Chrome and Firefox but as soon as I start testing in Edge, boom! problems all over the place. It appears that Edge is far more strict in its application of Content Security Policy and many scripts I am using no longer work. I am currently using the following third-party libraries:

1. [jQuery 3.1.1](https://jquery.com/)
2. [CSVExport](https://github.com/mikebald/CSV-Export)
3. [moment](https://momentjs.com/)
4. [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/)
5. [papaparse](http://papaparse.com/)

I have added CSP Trusted Sites where I believe it's applicable but I'm still seeing CSP errors in the Edge debugger. The biggest problem I'm seeing is that it's almost impossible to tell what script is being blocked. The error I'm seeing is:

> Resource violated directive 'script-src 'self' chrome-extension:
>   https://sfdc.azureedge.net *.cs12.visual.force.com
>   https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/' in Content-Security-Policy:
>   inline script. Resource will be blocked.

Typically, the "inline script" would be the actual source address, or at least from what I've seen online.

Does anyone know how to further debug this scenario? Are there avenues I can follow to figure out if it's blocking some scripts but not others? Also, why do the scripts work in Chrome and Firefox but not in Edge?

Please let me know if I can add additional details to make this scenario/question more clear.

Comment: Are you using static resources for loading the appropriate plugins?

Comment: Yes. All the resource are static resources. Also, as far as I understand, these libraries are self contained.